No puedo modificar el contenido html de un DIV a travès de de un success o un done de una invocaciòn AJAX
Tengo un div vacio con id="pagoIzipay" que está definido dentro de un modal.
Luego con javascript a travès de un AJAX intento dar un contenido al DIV antes mencionado pero no se actualiza.
El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:
HTML:
    <div id="pagoIzipay">

    </div>

JavaScript:
    $.ajax({
        url: "creaContenidoHTML.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        async : false,             
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (respuesta) {
            window.alert('MENSAJE 01 = '+respuesta);
            $('#pagoIzipay').html(respuesta);
            window.alert('MENSAJE 02 = '+$('#pagoIzipay').html() );
            document.getElementById("pagoIzipay").innerHTML = respuesta;
            window.alert('MENSAJE 03 = '+$('#pagoIzipay').html() );

        }
    }).done(function (respuesta) { 
            window.alert('MENSAJE 04 = '+respuesta);
            $('#pagoIzipay').html(respuesta);
            window.alert('MENSAJE 05 = '+$('#pagoIzipay').html() );
            document.getElementById("pagoIzipay").innerHTML = respuesta;
            window.alert('MENSAJE 06 = '+$('#pagoIzipay').html() );

        });

    window.alert('MENSAJE 07 = '+$('#pagoIzipay').html() );

Al ejecutarlo, tanto el MENSAJE 01 como el MENSAJE 04 me retornan el contenido que necesito asignarle al DIV en forma correcta.
Sin embargo MENSAJE 02 y MENSAJE 04 me retornan un valor "undefined" es decir el contenido del DIV no es modificado adecuadamente.
Asimismo MENSAJE 03 y MENSAJE 05 me retornan vacio (null) es decir el contenido del DIV tampoco es modificado correctamente.
Finalmente, el MENSAJE 07 me retorna también un valor "undefined".
Me pueden por favor ayudar a ver la forma de llenar el DIV con id="pagoIzipay" en forma correcta haciendo uso del resultado del valor de "respuesta" del success o del .done que devuelve el AJAX ?
Muchas gracias.

Comprueba que no exista otro elemento con la id pagoIzipay (Id repetida). Además agrega un console.log(respuesta) en success y borra todo el resto que es ruido, luego cuéntanos que te imprimió en consola
